# Why Java List can't remove a dynamic proxy object

Tags: java, list, proxy

I have a proxy object which is created by Proxy.newProxyInstance.
But It can't be removed from a List collection:

```
        Vector<ThirdPartyInterface>  all = new Vector<ThirdPartyInterface>();
    Set<ThirdPartyInterface>  all2 = new HashSet<ThirdPartyInterface>();
    List<ThirdPartyInterface>  all3 = new LinkedList<ThirdPartyInterface>();

    ThirdPartyClass realObject = new ThirdPartyClass();
    ThirdPartyInterface proxy = ProxyFactory.newInstance(realObject);

    all.addElement(proxy);      
    if (!all.remove(proxy)) {
        System.out.println("     ===>  proxy can't be found in Vector");
    }

    all2.add(proxy);
    if (!all2.remove(proxy)) {
        System.out.println("     ===>  proxy can't be found in HashSet");
    }

    all3.add(proxy);
    if (!all3.remove(proxy)) {
        System.out.println("     ===>  proxy can't be found in LinkedList");
    }
```

This code will print:

===>  proxy can't be found in Vector

===>  proxy can't be found in LinkedList

I tried on real object, it works as expected.

What is the reason ?

How can I fix it?

My code is on JDK7, the class has default equals and hashCode method.

Comment: You say it cannot be removed, are you sure that is even added instead?

Comment: Did you tried to print the hashcode of the object or to test equals method? Maybe equals is broken on proxy object.

Comment: @Isukthar , I checked the proxy has exact the same hash code as it real object, which is the memory address of the real object. It is expected.

Comment: @rakwaht, I checked all3.add(proxy); its size is one after this line